# pre flight HTTP OPTIONS call timesout with 500 Error sporadically

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, preflight

I have a C# based webAPI hosted on Azure WebApp.
Sporadically, the HTTP OPTIONS call fails with a 500 error.

The OPTIONS call is not handled by our code. So I assume the server handles it by itself.

I tried enabling logs but both event log and web server logs does not print anything other than that it failed with a 500 error.

Any ideas why this would happen?.

**Update:**
I see only the below error messages in the web server logs. No details 
Additionally I added code in my webAPI to handle options call, but the code does not go there. Not sure if I need to enable/disable something in web.confi.

2017-08-31 11:49:39 xxx.mywebsite.com OPTIONS /api/apiname StartDate=2017-08-25&EndDate=2017-08-31&X-ARR-LOG-ID=d86ffe7f-32c9-410b-8116-65833d5af7b9 443 - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/60.0.3112.113+Safari/537.36 - www.website.com  500 121 0 636 1612 230013

Comment: Azure App Service support HTTP OPTIONS method, and it works fine with my Azure WebApp. You said the HTTP OPTIONS call fails sporadically, do you get any detailed error infor? Besides, can you provide a sample to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @FredHan, I have updated my question with the error I get in web server log.